# Count specific words from text file - Java

Tags: java, file-read

I have a text file and I want to count the total number of specific words I have defined.

My code:

```
    String word1 = "aa";
    String word2 = "bb";

    int wordCount = 0;

     //creating File instance to reference text file in Java
    File text = new File("D:/project/log.txt");

    //Creating Scanner instnace to read File in Java
    Scanner s = new Scanner(text);

    //Reading each line of file using Scanner class
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        totalCount++;
        if (s.next().equals(word1) || s.next().equals(word2)) wordCount++;
    }

    System.out.println("Word count:  " + wordCount);
```

However, it only counts the number of 'aa's. It doesn't count the number of 'bb's.
what could be the problem?

Comment: Try answering the following questions: what does next() return? What happens if you call it twice?

Comment: @JBNizet The only attempt to educate the OP, make him come to the conclusion himself. Others hoping for a quick snack, like vultures (me included).

Comment: @PredragMaric at least your answer explains what the problem is rather than just providing alternative code without any explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call `s.next()`, it's finding the next word, so each loop is testing whether one word is "aa" or the next word is "bb". Within the loop, you would need to call `s.next()`, store the result in a variable, then check that with your two words.

Answer (score 3):

As other said: root of problem that you call next() twice. There just hint how to make your algo easy to extend:

```
Set<String> words = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("aa", "bb"));
...
while (s.hasNext()) {
    totalCount++;
    if (words.contains(s.next())) wordCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `s.next()` twice in `if` condition, and each call moves on to the next word.
Change your while loop to

```
while (s.hasNext()) {
    totalCount++;
    String word = s.next();
    if (word.equals(word1) || word.equals(word2)) wordCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
while (s.hasNext()) {
    totalCount++;
    String word = s.next()
    if (word.equals(word1) || word.equals(word2)) wordCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the you are calling `s.next()` twice. Each call reads a new token from the input.

Change it to :

```
while (s.hasNext()) {
    String str = s.next();
    totalCount++;
    if (str.equals(word1) || str.equals(word2)) wordCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You call next() two times in your if-condition.

try:

```
String word = s.next();

if ( word.equals(word1) ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String[] array = new String[]{"String 1", "String 2", "String 3"};

    for(int i=0; i < array.length; i++)
     {
                    System.out.println(array[i]);
                    wordCount=0;
                    while (s.hasNext()) 
                     {
                         totalCount++;
                         if (s.next().equals(array[i])) 
                         wordCount++;
                     }
                     System.out.println("each Word count:  " + wordCount);
     }
```